# problem on monotonicitiy

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I encountered a quite intuitive statement (economic theory research; no homework etc.) but I cannot find a way to prove it:

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a cadlag function (i.e. right continuous with left side limit existing in each point) that has no downward jumps (i.e. right limit is at least as high as left limit). Assume $f(0)>f(1)$. Then there exists a point $x_0$ and a $\epsilon>0$ such that either
(i) $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$ for all  $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$ and $f(x)<f(x_0)$ for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$ or
(ii) $f(x)> f(x_0)$ for all  $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$ and $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$.

Any ideas?

EDIT: (Roughly speaking, the statement above says: A function that decreases globally has to decrease locally somewhere.)

Comment: I minor correction: your statement is *A function that decreases globally has to be decrease **monotonously** locally somewhere.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous version of this answer was wrong. The correct answer is: this cannot be proven because it is not correct for all such functions.

It shouldn't be hard to construct the counterexample using [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which is continuous, but nowhere monotonous. We'd need to toy with the arguments a bit, and maybe multiply it by some constant, to achieve the desired domain and co-domain, but it disproves the statement from the question.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I am, however, not entirely convinced yet. There are two things. First, I think there are functions with infinitely many discontinuities that do not grow infinitely (e.g. let $q_1,q_2,...$ be an enumeration of the rationals and define $g:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ as $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{q_n\leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$ where $1_{q_n\leq x}$ is the indicator function for the event $q_n\leq x$). Second, I am not sure the statement is obvious as soon as $f$ is continuous (if it is, it would be a great help if someone could point it out to me).

Comment: Thinking of it; proving the statement for continuous functions would be enough: One could approximate the cadlag function arbitrarily closely by continuous functions that are strictly increasing around the discontinuities of the cadlag function (hence the properties (i) and (ii) would not be satisfied there).

Comment: Are you sure your $g$ is right continuous? Without that condition, I don't claim that there are finitely many discontinuing points. Nevertheless, I now see that what you want cannot be proven. It shouldn't be hard to construct the counterexample using [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) (you'll need to toy with the arguments a bit, and maybe multiply it by some constant). I'll edit my answer once we agree on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed the Weierstrass function is a counter example. So it cannot be proven.   On the g functions: You are right but letting h be the right derivative of g above should give an example that is right continuous and has the same properties.

Comment: I'm not sure it's (right) derivable, because every interval $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$, no matter how small it is, will contain discontinuing points. Of course, this is besides the point here, so let's not waste time on it. ;-)

Comment: oops, I meant right-limit not right-derivative in my last comment (which should exist as $g$ is monotone). However, as you said: it is a bit besides the point here anyway.